# Android Espresso test to check syncness between ViewPager's fragments and TabViews

Tags: android-espresso

I'd like to add a test to check that when the user swipe with the ViewPager or tap on a TabView, tabview's title is "synced" with the fragment's title.

To start playing with it I'm doing something simpler, but the test results in an infinite loop at the line onView(...).

Here is the code:

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyActivityTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        MyActivity.class);

@Test
@android.support.test.annotation.UiThreadTest
public void switchTab() {
    ((MyActivity)mActivityRule.getActivity()).addMyTab("Test 1", true);

    onView(withText("Test 1"))
            .perform(click())
            .check(matches(withText("Test 1")));
}
```

And this is my XML:

...

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</LinearLayout>
```

...

I'm adding tab dinamically to the adapter, as I'm using:

```java
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
...
myAdapter.add(...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the main problem was @android.support.test.annotation.UiThreadTest instead of @UiThread.

Regarding the rest, I've created a small example on GitHub to test TabLayout/ViewPager: https://github.com/MyWay/TabLayoutTest